# Facebook share - img thumb does not appear

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, sharing

I have a page Yummitube . If I share any link of the webpage on Facebook than no image thumb appears. My og:image is ok.

Let's say url is: http://www.yummitube.com/?id=936 
Meta og:image is the folowing:

The image is accesible.

Moreover Facebook linter shows that my og:image is ok.
but what I paste http://www.yummitube.com/?id=936 in facebook no thumb appears.

Any ideas? I tryed to use different sizes of image but that did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Your link in Open-graph debugger:** https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yummitube.com%2F%3Fid%3D936

**Problem found:** The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'fb:admins'

**Two solution found:**

1. Trim admins string because most probably it is generating some extra
   space
2. Provide og:type

Comment: Thank you!

I am unhappy I cannot rate your answer up because I am new here

Comment: I have noticed one important thing that og:image size should be not smaller than 200x200

Comment: interesting. is the 200x200 limit documented somewhere? I have a similar issue http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15234775/g-doesnt-accept-my-ogimage

Comment: JonasNarvas: No problem buddy :-)

@MotoTribe: I think it is not documented but it is recommended. One more thing: OG tags are much simpler and easier to implement than G+ tags but we have nothing to do here.